# CORS Error on localhost:9000 angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cors

while running app locally, I am getting following error:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

and

```
SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:9000 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
```

However, when deployed on server, it works fine. Can you please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to read up on CORS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS is a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your header by adding it to the config

```
 myApp.config({
      $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
      delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT';
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = true;
      });
```